# ArrayList to Int?

Tags: java, arraylist

I need a bit of help since I am a not really good in java. I need to return only the words which length is odd ? But I am getting an error.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListOdd {

     public static ArrayList<Integer> lengths(ArrayList<String> list) {
      ArrayList<Integer> lengthList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for (String s : list)
            lengthList.add(s.length());
        return lengthList;
     }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<String>  
        list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("yoy");
        list.add("lmao");
        list.add("lol");
        list.add("kk");
        list.add("bbb");

        ArrayList<Integer> lengths = lengths(list);
  
        ArrayList oddList = new ArrayList();
        oddList = (ArrayList)list.clone();
        if (lengths % 2 != 0) {
        System.out.println("Strings with odd length are: " + oddList);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do not write `ArrayList oddList = new ArrayList();` without the generic types. Always use the generic types when working with the collections API.

Comment: What did you mean by `if (lengths % 2 != 0)`?

Comment: When you write `lengths % 2 != 0` it means that you are trying to find the remainder of `lengths`, an `ArrayList`, divided by 2. This doesn't work because `ArrayList` is not an integer. You have to loop through `lengths` and remove every entry that isn't odd. In which case, you will only have an array that contains the length of every word and not the word itself.

Comment: Using `clone` is also generally discouraged (it is regarded to have been a mistake).

Comment: Post your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to perform Integer operation on a list.  'lengths' is an ArrayList and operation % is non applicable to it. Also, I think you shouldn't use cloning here and just iterate over `list` and check if each element is odd - print it or add to another list if it is.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to implement a separate method that copies the strings with odd length:

```java
public static List<String> oddLengths(List<String> list) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : list) {
        if (s.length() % 2 != 0) {
            result.add(s);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then just call this method in `main` method:

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("yoy");
list.add("lmao");
list.add("lol");
list.add("kk");
list.add("bbb");

List<String> oddList = oddLengths(list);

System.out.println("Strings with odd length are: " + oddList);
```

Less efficient approach would be to copy the initial list and then remove all strings with *even* length using `removeIf` operation:

```java
List<String> oddList2 = new ArrayList<>(list); // no need to use clone
oddList2.removeIf(s -> s.length() % 2 == 0); // removing all strings with even length
System.out.println("Strings with odd length are: " + oddList2);
```

---

It is convenient to use Stream API with filter operation to achieve the same result:

```java
public static List<String> oddLengths(List<String> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.length() % 2 != 0)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: `result.add(s.length())` should probably be `result.add(s)`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper, right, I edited it out.

Answer (score 0):

modify lengths methods

```
 public static void main(String []args){
         ArrayList<String>  
        list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("yoy");
        list.add("lmao");
        list.add("lol");
        list.add("kk");
        list.add("bbb");

        ArrayList<String> lengths = lengths(list);
        
        
        System.out.println(lengths.toString());
     }
     
     
     public static ArrayList<String> lengths(ArrayList<String> list) {
      ArrayList<String> lengthList = new ArrayList<String>();
      for (String s : list)
            if(s.length() % 2 != 0)
               lengthList.add(s);
        return lengthList;
     }
```